# Speeding up `any` with list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, any

I am using `any` with a list comprehension. I would like to break the list comprehension when `any` returns `True`. For example,

```
import time

def f(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x

beginTime = time.time()
result = any([f(x) == 0 for x in [0,1,3,5,7]])
endTime = time.time()

print(endTime - beginTime)
```

The above code prints **10 seconds** although it could break the iteration after first `True`.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with list comprehensions. I'd use a "normal" loop in such a case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to avoid forming the list first:

```
result = any(f(x) == 0 for x in [0,1,3,5,7])
```

(the square brackets of the list comprehension are gone.)

Note that `any` has a short-circuiting behaviour in either case, but what differs is the lack of forming the whole list.

Comment: Wow, I tried to use the starred version, `any(*[f(x) ...])` but didn't think of that. Thanks Mustafa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator, as told by Mustafa, but retrieve only first element of truth.
The generator non necessary must be consumed totally, and walrus operator do the rest

```
import time
def f(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x

beginTime = time.time()
result = next((wr  for x in [0,1,3,5,7] if (wr := f(x)) ==0))
endTime = time.time()

print(endTime - beginTime)
```

This takes only minimum time to retrieve first ocurrence